# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

Tags: python

I'm working on Python and have defined a variable called "_headers" as shown below

```
_headers = ('id',
                'recipient_address_1',
                'recipient_address_2',
                'recipient_address_3',
                'recipient_address_4',
                'recipient_address_5',
                'recipient_address_6',
                'recipient_postcode',
                )
```

and in order to write this into an output file, I've written the following statement but it throws me the error "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'"

```
with open(outfile, 'w') as f:  
            outfile.write(self._headers)  
            print done
```

Please help

Comment: You meant : `f.write(self._headers)`?

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer which helped you the most.

Answer (score 31):

You want `f.write`, not `outfile.write`...

`outfile` is the name of the file as a string.  `f` is the file object.

As noted in the comments, `file.write` expects a string, not a sequence.  If you wanted to write data from a sequence, you could use `file.writelines`.  e.g. `f.writelines(self._headers)`.  But beware, this doesn't append a newline to each line.  You need to do that yourself. :)

Comment: Sorry for that, after the change "f.write" I now get the following error 
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple

Comment: You can't write a tuple with a file object's `write` method. Perhaps call `str` or `repr` on it first?

Comment: @user1345260: What exactly do you want written? If you want it to appear similar to the source, use `repr`. If you want something to be shared with other programs, use `pickle.dump` or `json.dump`. If you want it to be formatted in some human-readable way, write the appropriate formatting code.

Comment: Or put your data into a list instead of a tuple.

Comment: You say that outfiel is a string and that file.write expects a string not a sequence Isn't that's contradicting? Could you elaborate

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you want 1 header per line, try this:

```
with open(outfile, 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(self._headers))  
    print done
```

Answer (score 2):

To stay as close to your script as possible:

```
>>> _headers = ('id',
...             'recipient_address_1',
...             'recipient_address_2',
...             'recipient_address_3',
...             'recipient_address_4',
...             'recipient_address_5',
...             'recipient_address_6',
...             'recipient_postcode',
...            )
>>> done = "Operation successfully completed"
>>> with open('outfile', 'w') as f:
...     for line in _headers:
...         f.write(line + "\n")
...     print done
Operation successfully completed
```